# Symfony 3 and Swift Mailer: how to configure service

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

In my symfony project I try to configure an email controller without success.

services.yml

```
emailController:        
    class:     AppBundle\Controller\emailController
    public: true
    arguments:            
        $mailer: '@mailer'
```

emailController.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class emailController extends Controller
{
    protected $mailer;

function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer) {       
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
}   


public function sendMail($email){

    $message = (new \Swift_Message())       
    ->setSubject('send mail')  
    ->setFrom('xx@yy.com')      
    ->setTo($email)
    ->setBody('TEST')
    ->setContentType("text/html");

    $this->mailer->send($message);

    return 1;       
}    

}
```

Symfony return this message:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Controller\emailController::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Swift_Mailer, none given,

I try some configuration and option but without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is, that you are configuring your controller as a service, but your router probably does not refer to the configured service, only to the class name.

You can use annotations:

```
@Route(service="emailController")
```

or the typical yaml format to refer to your controller as a service:

```
email:
path:     /email
defaults: { _controller: emailController:indexAction }
```

Note that both refer to the service id specified in your definition above, not the actual class name. You can read more about the concept of controllers as services in the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html

**edit:** As a sidenote since you seem to use a new Symfony version you might want to check out injecting services directly into actions using the `resolve_controller_arguments` tag: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services-as-controller-arguments

Answer (score 0):

<del>You define a controller as a service which is not how it's intended to be but whatever; both controller and services are normal PHP classes.</del>

Anyway, the aforementioned error message says it all, your service definition needs to supply the correct arguments (none given) e.g. like that:

```
arguments: ['@mailer']
```

Please try this.